# Proof that this sequence is divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This is the question:

Prove that this sequence is divergent.

$a_n = (1+\frac 1n)^{nlog_2n}$

Many Thanks. I think its an easy question, but I just need an idea how I ment to write my answers. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write
\begin{align}
a_n &= \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n\log_2n} = e^{n\log_2n\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})} \\
&= 
e^{n\log_2n\cdot \left(\frac{1}{n}- \frac{1}{2n^2}+ o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)} = e^{\log_2n\cdot \left(1- \frac{1}{2n}+ o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)} \\
&= n^{1/\ln 2} e^{o\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)}\operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty}
n^{1/\ln 2} \end{align}
which goes to infinity (where we used $e^{o(1)}\to 1$).

Comment: (Note that here, you also get the exact rate of convergence of the sequence — a the price of a slightly more general cumbersome approach). If you want to get a faster proof, observe that $b_n\stackrel{\rm{}def}{=} \ln a_n$ goes to infinity (it's easier to show); hence $a_n$ does too.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n=1+{n\choose1}\left({1\over n}\right)+{n\choose2}\left({1\over n}\right)^2+\cdots\ge2$$

hence

$$a_n\ge2^{\log_2n}=n$$